# hazelcast client exception when connecting to server

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to use hazelcast v3.2.4 (same version on server and client).  The server (as simple an implementation that I could put in place) is running on a server.  The client tries to connect to the remote server - the server prints the authentication requests but I receive the following log outputs (including exceptions) - any ideas on what I can do differently (copying both log output and config file).  I am trying to connect via TCP/IP and I checked for network connectivity - I could not see anything blocking the connection.

**Line of Code mentioned in stack:**

```
final ClientConfig config= new XmlClientConfigBuilder("config/hazelcast.xml").build();
HazelcastInstance hcast = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);   //this is mentioned in stack trace
```

**Config**

```
<hazelcast-client xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-client-config-3.1.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name> 
        <password>dev-pass</password> 
    </group>
    <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
    <network>
       <cluster-members>
            <address>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</address>
        </cluster-members>
        <smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
        <redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
        <connection-pool-size>30</connection-pool-size>

        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="false">
                <interface>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</interface>
            </tcp-ip>
            <aws enabled="false">
                <access-key>my-access-key</access-key>
                <secret-key>my-secret-key</secret-key>
                <region>us-west-1</region>
                <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
                <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
                <tag-key>type</tag-key>
                <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
            </aws>
        </join>
        <interfaces enabled="false">
            <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
        </interfaces>
        <ssl enabled="false" />
        <socket-interceptor enabled="false" />
        <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
            <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
            <salt>thesalt</salt>
            <password>thepass</password>
            <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
        </symmetric-encryption>
    </network>
```

**Log output**

```
Sep 05, 2014 4:06:02 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_dev][3.2.4] is STARTING
Sep 05, 2014 4:06:02 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_dev][3.2.4] is STARTED
Sep 05, 2014 4:06:02 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_dev][3.2.4] is CLIENT_CONNECTED
Sep 05, 2014 4:06:02 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientClusterService
INFO: 

Members [1] {
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5701
}

Sep 05, 2014 4:06:22 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientPartitionService
SEVERE: Error while fetching cluster partition table!
com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableIOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.getOrConnect(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.tryToConnect(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:261)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceImpl.send(ClientInvocationServiceImpl.java:149)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceImpl.invokeOnTarget(ClientInvocationServiceImpl.java:59)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.getPartitionsFrom(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:105)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.getInitialPartitions(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:94)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.start(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:60)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.start(HazelcastClient.java:223)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:186)
    at com.xxx.test.HCastClientAccessor.getHCastInstance(HCastClientAccessor.java:55)
    at com.xxx.test.HCastTest.<clinit>(HCastTest.java:12)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:119)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.getOrConnect(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:316)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:45)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$ConnectionProcessor.call(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:384)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$ConnectionProcessor.call(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:332)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CompletableFutureTask.run(CompletableFutureTask.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(PoolExecutorThreadFactory.java:59)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:708)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:115)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$ConnectionProcessor.call(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:365)
    ... 11 more
```

**Server output**

```
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Accepting socket connection from /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49705
Sep 05, 2014 4:05:57 PM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] 5701 accepted socket connection from /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49705
Sep 05, 2014 4:05:57 PM com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationRequest
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Received auth from Connection [/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49705 -> null] live=true, client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, successfully authenticated
Sep 05, 2014 4:09:43 PM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Connection [Address[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:49705] lost. Reason: java.io.IOException[Connection reset by peer]
Sep 05, 2014 4:09:43 PM com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngine
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Destroying ClientEndpoint{conn=Connection [/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49705 -> Address[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:49705] live=false, client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, uuid='70afcf60-96e0-444d-8981-3aa983530514', firstConnection=true, authenticated=true}
Sep 05, 2014 4:09:43 PM com.hazelcast.nio.ReadHandler
WARNING: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-0 Closing socket to endpoint Address[192.168.101.106]:49705, Cause:java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

**Update:**

I switched to this client config but I still get an exception on the client end.  I copied the server and client output - the server receives the connection request but then on the client end, I see the same error as mentioned above **"SEVERE: Error while fetching cluster partition table!"** - same trace as above.

**New client config**

```
<hazelcast-client xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-client-config-3.2.4.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name> 
        <password>dev-pass</password> 
    </group>
    <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
    <network>
       <cluster-members>
            <address>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</address>
        </cluster-members>
        <smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
        <redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
        <connection-timeout>60000</connection-timeout>
        <connection-attempt-limit>10</connection-attempt-limit>
        <connection-pool-size>30</connection-pool-size>
    </network>
        <executor-pool-size>40</executor-pool-size> <!-- added -->

</hazelcast-client>
```

**Server output:**

```
Sep 07, 2014 5:57:01 PM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketAcceptor
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Accepting socket connection from /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58521
Sep 07, 2014 5:57:01 PM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] 5701 accepted socket connection from /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58521
Sep 07, 2014 5:57:03 PM com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationRequest
INFO: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Received auth from Connection [/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58521 -> null] live=true, client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, successfully authenticated
```

**Client output**

```
Sep 07, 2014 5:58:04 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientPartitionService
SEVERE: Error while fetching cluster partition table!
com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableIOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.getOrConnect(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.tryToConnect(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:261)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceImpl.send(ClientInvocationServiceImpl.java:149)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceImpl.invokeOnTarget(ClientInvocationServiceImpl.java:59)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.getPartitionsFrom(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:105)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.getInitialPartitions(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:94)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.start(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:60)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.start(HazelcastClient.java:223)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:186)
```

**Update**

I tried this for client and server and I got the same exception as above - what am I doing wrong:

**Client**
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig().addAddress("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
          HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);

**Server**

```
HazelcastInstance hcast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
```

**Update**
In short, make sure the config for both server and client are correct (do not mix up tags from one set to another).  For the server, ensure that the hazelcast server is listening on the external IP address (not the loopback addresS), that there are no firewall settings blocking the connection (on client, server or in-between).  Thanks to Peter - I'm back to using hazelcast and enjoying my experience of using this tool.  Strongly recommended!

Comment: The Hazelcast client configuration isn't valid. It is a mixture of client and server configuration, for example <network><join> section doesn't exist for the client. Can you enable schema validation in your ide.

Comment: Thanks to pveentjer - besides config and firewall changes, the interface needed to be the external IP address on which the server was supposed to listen on (as opposed to the local loopback address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the XML problems for the client, I don't see anything obvious wrong.

My usual approach is the following; try to run server and client on the same JVM, then at least you have made sure that there is no problem.
I always verify the basics before I'm going to waste a second on network problems.

Once you have verified that, check the following section.
My gut feeling is that there is something with the firewall. The first section contains configuration information about `iptables`, the second contains a second to test the network connection.

**iptables**
If you are making use of `iptables`, the following rule can be added to allow for outbound traffic from ports 33000-31000:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p TCP --dport 33000:31000 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

and to control incoming traffic from any address to port 5701:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 5701 -j ACCEPT
```

and to allow incoming multicast traffic:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
```

**Connectivity test**.
If you are having troubles because machines won't join a cluster, you might check the network connectivity between the 2 machines. You can use a tool called [iperf](https://iperf.fr/) for that.
On one machine you execute:

```
iperf -s -p 5701
```

This means that you are listening at port 5701.

At the other machine you execute the following command:

```
iperf -c 192.168.1.107 -d -p 5701
```

Where you replace `192.168.1.107` by the ip address of your first machine.
If you run the command and you get output like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5701
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.1.107, TCP port 5701
TCP window size: 59.4 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local 192.168.1.105 port 40524 connected with 192.168.1.107 port 5701
[  4] local 192.168.1.105 port 5701 connected with 192.168.1.107 port 33641
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.2 sec  55.8 MBytes  45.7 Mbits/sec
[  5]  0.0-10.3 sec  6.25 MBytes  5.07 Mbits/sec
```

You know the 2 machines can connect to each other.
However if you are seeing something like this:

```
Server listening on TCP port 5701
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
connect failed: No route to host.
```

Then you know that you might have a network connection problem on your hands.

Comment: thanks for responding - the iperf test works between the machines (i did that before posting the question but may have left it out of the post).  I think there is something wrong the xml for the server and/or client (as you mentioned - the client) which might be causing the issue.  You may have added this on github based on my question - my experience has been that I did not come across a client xml config in the documentation (I may have missed it) - I only noticed the "client" part in the config via a search result.

Comment: I realized its a ClientConfig and not a config but was not sure right away that it required a different XML config (its clear to me now) as I have gone through additional client configuration settings

Comment: I tried changing the client config (update copied above). I have to wonder whether I'm doing something incorrect pertaining to partitions

Comment: I have tried with partition-group enabled="false" and true - neither changed anything for me.  Next, I will simply try the API calls instead of the client XML but I'm not certain if that's the issue.  I will check the local setup as well (I think I did before posting this question and I experienced the same issue on the client side).

Comment: I have tried different permutations - I can connect locally but not from my desktop to the server (will try a different server on a different network just to tick all the boxes)

Comment: Can you run both client and server on the same machine, with the client configuration you have (only fix the member address). And see if that works. When I get unexplained behavior I try to cut parts out of the problem domain until I end up with a working system; and then slowly make things more complex again.

Comment: Could it be that there is some nat translation in the way?

If you want to show Hazelcast, and you don't know what the problem is with your current environment. Just create a few ec2 instances. I'm using them all day long.

I don't use the AWS discovery btw; only tcp/ip-discovery and my clients (if I have them) are also in EC2; preventing any NAT translation problems.

Comment: Can you send me your project at peter dot veentjer at hazelcast dot com so I can have a look at it. I'll check if there are any obvious errors; but I'm pretty sure it is something in your network. And you probably run into exactly the same problems with other products (networking in Hazelcast is very simple to setup).

And the partitiontable problem is one of the first operations executed, so that is where the problem is encountered. It isn't the partitiontable operation which is the problem; it probably is your network.

Comment: thanks - much appreciated for being patient as well.  I know I was ranting online for which I apologize

Answer (score 0):

The error you're mentioning appears to come from the following (ClientPartitionServiceImpl) where it calls the GetPartitionRequest and passes in the address.  Can you check what you are passing in as address (may require for you to build hazelcast with the version you're using) or check the interfaces/config file being used in more detail.

```
public ClientPartitionServiceImpl(HazelcastClient client) {
    this.client = client;
}

public void start() {
    getInitialPartitions();
    client.getClientExecutionService().scheduleWithFixedDelay(new RefreshTask(), INITIAL_DELAY, PERIOD, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public void refreshPartitions() {
    try {
        client.getClientExecutionService().execute(new RefreshTask());
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException ignored) {
        EmptyStatement.ignore(ignored);
    }
}

private class RefreshTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        if (updating.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            try {
                final ClientClusterService clusterService = client.getClientClusterService();
                final Address master = clusterService.getMasterAddress();
                final PartitionsResponse response = getPartitionsFrom(master);
                if (response != null) {
                    processPartitionResponse(response);
                }
            } catch (HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException ignored) {
                EmptyStatement.ignore(ignored);
            } finally {
                updating.set(false);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void getInitialPartitions() {
    final ClientClusterService clusterService = client.getClientClusterService();
    final Collection<MemberImpl> memberList = clusterService.getMemberList();
    for (MemberImpl member : memberList) {
        final Address target = member.getAddress();
        PartitionsResponse response = getPartitionsFrom(target);
        if (response != null) {
            processPartitionResponse(response);
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot get initial partitions!");
}

private PartitionsResponse getPartitionsFrom(Address address) {
    try {
        final Future<PartitionsResponse> future =
                client.getInvocationService().invokeOnTarget(new GetPartitionsRequest(), address);
        return client.getSerializationService().toObject(future.get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.severe("Error while fetching cluster partition table!", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**GetPartitionsRequest**

```
public final class GetPartitionsRequest extends CallableClientRequest implements Portable, RetryableRequest {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        InternalPartitionService service = getService();
        service.firstArrangement();
        ClusterService clusterService = getClientEngine().getClusterService();
        Collection<MemberImpl> memberList = clusterService.getMemberList();
        Address[] addresses = new Address[memberList.size()];
        Map<Address, Integer> addressMap = new HashMap<Address, Integer>(memberList.size());
        int k = 0;
        for (MemberImpl member : memberList) {
            Address address = member.getAddress();
            addresses[k] = address;
            addressMap.put(address, k);
            k++;
        }
        InternalPartition[] partitions = service.getPartitions();
        int[] indexes = new int[partitions.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            Address owner = partitions[i].getOwnerOrNull();
            int index = -1;
            if (owner != null) {
                final Integer idx = addressMap.get(owner);
                if (idx != null) {
                    index = idx;
                }

            }
            indexes[i] = index;
        }
        return new PartitionsResponse(addresses, indexes);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServiceName() {
        return InternalPartitionService.SERVICE_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public int getFactoryId() {
        return ClientPortableHook.ID;
    }

    @Override
    public int getClassId() {
        return ClientPortableHook.GET_PARTITIONS;
    }

    @Override
    public Permission getRequiredPermission() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: looking into this.  I can connect on the same computer (client/server code and config works) but I get the partition exception whenever I try to connect across from one computer to another (regardless of what machine I use).

Comment: Simplify your environment till something that works. Networking is extremely basic behavior in Hazelcast and has been tested more than enough. It must be something in your network.

Comment: @pveentjer I'm updating my post - I tried the default client and server and I get the same exception with v3.2.4 - unless mistaken, that uses the hazelcast-default.xml and not my config.  Why does that not work?

Comment: Does it work when you run client and server on the same machine? Did you verify that?

Comment: it runs on the same computer - the issue happens when I connect from one computer to another

Comment: Ok. Then probably the configuration is fine.

Are you sure there is no firewall? I have seen enough issues with those things.

Comment: I'm emailing you the project shortly - its as simple as I could make it.  I'm not sure if you use gradle/sbt/maven or just ant.  I'm going to simplify the package the best I can.

Comment: also, I'm not sure if I can assume the config is fine (specially on the server) - is it possible the server config is messed up and it only manifests itself when I connect from a different computer potentially messing up the address being passed in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60849/discussion-between-pveentjer-and-user3813256).

Answer (score 0):

Just will add some situations, that I faced for the "Error while fetching cluster partition table"

- for ipv6: check http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/ipv6.html page. If you use ipv6 don't foget to set "hazelcast.prefer.ipv4.stack" to true on server
- for ipv6: for some reasons everything still doesn't work for client if you don't set "" For ipv4 it works with "enabled=false". I use one single machine and don't need the cluster, but need clients connected. Magic: client can connect to server with "tcp-ip enabled=false" if using ipv4, but cannot if using ipv6.